# Rails app works fine with S3 using carrierwave locally, crashes on Heroku with error message 'Unable to autoload constant'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm using the carrierwave gem to store user uploads to S3 in a Rails engine I mounted to an online store app of mine. Everything works fine locally, and I checked S3 to make sure my files are being uploaded.

I deployed my app to Heroku, and the deployment was successful. I also set my AWS access key, secret key and bucket variables on Heroku fine. However, when I try to open my app's page, I get the 'Application Error' page. When I look at my Heroku logs, I noticed the following line:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:464:in `load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant Prodeng::ProductImageUploader, expected /app/prodeng/app/uploaders/prodeng/product_image_uploader.rb to define it (LoadError)
```

Prodeng is the namespace for my Rails engine that I mounted in my app. I really am unsure why this is happening, but this is also the first time I've ever created a Rails engine and mounted it inside of an app.

Here is my product_image_uploader.rb (prodeng/app/uploaders/prodeng/product_image_uploader.rb) file in my Rails engine:

```
class ProductImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [200, 150]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_white_list
  #   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

Here is my carrierwave.rb file inside my Rails engine (/prodeng/app/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb)

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY"],                       
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV["AWS_SECRET_KEY"]                        
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV["AWS_BUCKET"]                     
end
```

Here is my prodeng.gemspec file

```
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)

# Maintain your gem's version:
require "prodeng/version"

# Describe your gem and declare its dependencies:
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = "prodeng"
  s.version     = Prodeng::VERSION
  s.authors     = ["TODO: Your name"]
  s.email       = ["TODO: Your email"]
  s.homepage    = "TODO"
  s.summary     = "TODO: Summary of Prodeng."
  s.description = "TODO: Description of Prodeng."

  s.files = Dir["{app,config,db,lib}/**/*", "MIT-LICENSE", "Rakefile", "README.rdoc"]
  s.test_files = Dir["test/**/*"]

  s.add_dependency "rails", "~> 4.0.8"

  s.add_dependency "carrierwave"
  s.add_dependency "rmagick"

  s.add_development_dependency "sqlite3"
end
```

I apologize if I've left out anything needed to figure out this question. Any help or pointing in the right direction will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to include my app's Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.8'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'prodeng', :path => './prodeng'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'fog'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Comment: Should your class name be Prodeng::ProductImageUploader?  (missing namespace)

Comment: That was exactly the problem. How did I miss that? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Swards pointed out in the comments, I left out my engine's namespace when creating my ProductImageUploader class. The class should've been written like this:

```
class Prodeng::ProductImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
```